# Get JSON string with httpClient

Tags: c#, .net, json, async-await, httpclient

I am using Xamarin Forms and I am trying to get a JSON string for a file located here. However I do not seem to be able to get the Json string out. This is my code:

```
public async static Task<string> GetJson(string URL)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        // ... Read the string.
        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

private static void FindJsonString()
{
    Task t = new Task(GetJson("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37802978/policyHolder.json"));
    t.Start();
    t.Wait();
    string Json = t.ToString();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I get these 2 Errors in relation to this line

```
Task t = new Task(GetJson("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37802978/policyHolder.json"));
```

> Error 1
> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Task(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Action'

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Something back you didn't expect?  Or nothing at all?

Comment: It won't compile because of this line Task t = new Task(GetJson("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37802978/policyHolder.json"));

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

That is because `new Task` is expecting an `Action` delegate, while you pass it a `Task<string>`.

Don't use `new Task`, use `Task.Run`. Also, note that you're passing in an `async` method, you might want to `await GetJson`:

So you either need

```
var task = Task.Run(() => GetJson("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37802978/policyHolder.json"));
```

Or if you want to `await` inside `Task.Run`:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await GetJson("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37802978/policyHolder.json"));
```

They will also differ in return type. The former will return a `Task<Task<string>>`, while the latter will return `Task<string>`

TPL guidelines state async method should end with a `Async` postfix. Consider renaming `GetJson` to `GetJsonAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Yuval. But how do I get the return string from GetJson? is in the the var task?

Comment: `await` semantically removes the Task from the return type.  So, `await GetJson()` is the Json string.  Calling `.Result` on a task will also accomplish the same result, but blocks your thread in doing so.

Comment: When `Task.Run` runs ti completion, you can access it inside `task.Result`. Note that if you access the `Result` property before the task finishes, it **will block** like a synchronous method.